# Chatter:Feed in VisualForce with Topic Id

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, visualforce-component

Trying to use the chatter:feed visualforce tag with a topic id as the entity id and the feed isn't rendering at all.
From what I've read, it seems like this should be no problem, but I'm getting nothing from it.
 I've stripped the page down to just the feed component with a hardcoded topic id. Are topic's no longer supported as entity ids for chatter:feed? If they are not, what are my options to show a topic feed in a visualforce page other than using the ConnectAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Have done this in the past.. works for me..

`<chatter:feed entityId="{!$Setup.apexCodeSettings__c.XXXChatterTopicId__c}" id="chatterFeed" />`

FYI.. I'm using a custom setting to store the chatter topic id

Comment: I tried the setup you suggested. Here's my code:

<apex:page >
<!--<topics:widget entity="a1ue0000001BQKR" />-->
<chatter:feed entityId="{!$Setup.Link_Event_Topic_Id__c.Event_Topic_Id__c}" /> 
<apex:outputText value ="{!$Setup.Link_Event_Topic_Id__c.Event_Topic_Id__c}"/>
</apex:page>

With this, the outputText shows the topic id that I set, but the feed still does not render.